# Does strict equality guarantees loose equality

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm starting to write unit tests for my nodeJS/Javascript app with Mocha.

For my equality assertions tests I decided to use

- `assert.strictEqual` to test for equality
- `assert.notEqual` to test for difference

The idea behind this is to enforce the use of the strict equality operator (`===` and `!==`) but to be sure no error will be produced if `==` and `!=` are used.

But it led me to a question :

For every possible `a` does `a === b` means `a == b` and does `a !== b` means `a != b` ?

Comment: Your title and your question ask different things - might want to clear those up.

Comment: @Paddy done, if you feel like the title isn't good enough, please feel free to suggest me one :)

Comment: Are `a` and `b` same data type, like both numerics or strings etc?

Comment: @HarshGupta There is no assumptions on `a` and `b` (object, string, functions, same type, different types, ...)

Comment: In that case, answer is simply No. Double (in)equality invokes type-coercion while triple does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The === and !== ensure that no only are the items considered 'equal' but that they are the same type - no type coercion is done:

```
"1" == 1 //true
"1" === 1 //false
```

It's the same for the inequality operator:

```
"2" != 1 //true
"2" !== 1 //true

"1" != 1 //false
"1" !== 1 //true
```

So, short answer, "For every possible a does a == b means a === b and does a != b means a !== b ?" - No.

Comment: I realized I made a silly mistake in my question. I meaned `For every possible a does a === b means a == b and does a !== b means a != b ?`. But your example proves both assumptions are wrong so thank you

Answer (score 1):

No. For example `0 !== false` yet `0 == false`.

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Comment: @Juhana How is it not?

Comment: The question is whether `a === b` guarantees `a == b` and whether `a !== b` guarantees `a != b`. You're answering a third case, `a !== b` and `a == b`, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @Juhana my answer is a counter example to the second case. Also if I'm not mistaken those two questions are equivalent to the question "are == and === equivalent"

Comment: If you followed it to the logical conclusion, then it would answer the question. But just showing a case where `!==` and `==` are equivalent does not yet prove that the inverse is true.

Comment: @Juhana I believe it does. When asking whether `a === b <=> a == b`, which OP unknowingly did, a single counter-example is enough to prove the assumption is wrong. At this point I'm wondering whether there is a real misunderstanding between us or if we are arguing semantics. Anyway it's fine by me !

Answer (score 1):

The `===` comparison is stronger than `==`.  A `==` comparison just checks if two values are equal, performing type conversions as needed.  A `===` comparison check that both the type and the value are the same.  So `a === b` implies `a == b`, and `a != b` implies `a !== b`.

Example:

```
"100" ==  100    ->  true
"100" === 100    ->  false
"100" !=  100    ->  false
"100" !== 100    ->  true
```

Comment: I guess the question is whether `a == b` implies `a === b` and not the other way, which is simply not true.